# why does gpg --list-secret-keys show keys in pubring.kbx

Tags: gnupg

When I do gpg --list-secret-keys I get a response of a key I've imported but it's located in ~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx

I exported my public.key and private.key each with gpg --import and when I imported the private.key it asked me for my secret passphrase so I assumed it all went well.

I saw a blog post earlier and their output from --list-secret-keys returned a result located in ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg where as my result comes from ~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx

My concern is that I've imported them wrong.  Is it ok to have my private key returned from the pubring file ? Or is this just there because my paired public key is located there?

Answer (score 5):

Everything is fine. Up to GnuPG 2.1 private keys got stored in `secring.gpg`. Later versions merged it into `pubring.kbx`.

See [GnuPG FAQ: Removal of the secret keyring](https://gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html#nosecring).

Comment: Danken, el magnefico!